# NSPredicate %K with OR raise NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: ios, nspredicate

So my object has a reserve word `no`, so I have to use %K in the predicate. When I use the %K as the only condition, it works, however when I add it to a chain or conditions, exception is raised.

This raise an exception:

```
NSPredicate *predicateTemplate = [NSPredicate  predicateWithFormat:@"first_name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR last_name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR nickname CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR group == %i OR %K = %i", searchText, searchText, searchText, value, value, @"no", value];
```

Exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Contact 0x828dbd0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key (null).'
```

This works:

```
NSPredicate *predicateTemplate = [NSPredicate  predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %i", @"no", value];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one has 6 format specifiers and 7 variables. You are either missing a format specifier or you have an extra variable. Most likely you need to remove one of the 1st two `value` references.

Comment: My bad, there's an extra variable. At first without the %K, I have put an extra variable without noticing it, and it doesn't raise anything, so when I add another condition and it gives an error.

Comment: So are you saying that my answer was correct or not? I can't tell from your comment.